# AngularJS validation select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, jquery-selectbox

have selectbox in form, i try make validate but not work same what i do before for input type text. What i do wrong ?

example

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Email<sup>*</sup></label>

                                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                                            <div class="input-icon-right">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="example@example.com" type="email" ng-model="patient.email" name="email" required>
                                                <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required" style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.email.$touched">Add your email</p>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                            </div>
```

this code work good and show error message when field empty.

and this code with select box no work correctly, every time select no empty but have a choice -Select-, how i can show error when no chice another.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{getWord('Gender')}}<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender"
                                            data-placeholder="Tên Cơ Sở"
                                            ng-change="changeGender()"
                                            style="width: 100%;" requied name="gender">
                                        <option value="">-{{getWord('Select')}}-</option>
                                        <option ng-repeat="item in genders" value="{{item.name}}">
                                            {{getWord(item.name)}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <p ng-show="myForm.gender.$error.required" style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.gender.$touched">Please choice gender</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You are spelling required wrong?
"<select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender"
                                            data-placeholder="Tên Cơ Sở"
                                            ng-change="changeGender()"
                                            style="width: 100%;" requied name="gender">"

Comment: what wrong? i need show error message when no choice this select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood. You need to show error when user have not selected anything or have not touched the dropdown.

**Change this line:**

```
<p ng-show="myForm.gender.$error.required" style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.gender.$touched">Please choice gender</p>
```

**To This:**

```
<p style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.gender.$pristine || myForm.gender.$error.required">Please choice gender</p>
```

And Also there is a **spelling mistake**. change `requied` to `required`

***Correct this too:***

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender"
        data-placeholder="Tên Cơ Sở"
        ng-change="changeGender()"
        style="width: 100%;" requied 
name="gender">
```

***To This:***

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender"
        ng-change="changeGender()"
        style="width: 100%;" required 
name="gender">
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: when reload page i see my error message and -select- cannot choice.

Comment: Are their any `options` in select ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{getWord('Gender')}}<sup>*</sup></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender"
                                        data-placeholder="Tên Cơ Sở"
                                        ng-change="changeGender()"
                                        style="width: 100%;" required name="gender">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>-{{getWord('Select')}}-</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="item in genders" value="{{item.name}}">
                                        {{getWord(item.name)}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                                <p style="color:red" ng-if="!myForm.gender.$pristine && myForm.gender.$error.required">Please choice gender</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Can you try this ?

Comment: Look Kush response requied => required

Comment: work allready, but need make when touched and no choice any. Right now when open form imput allready have a allert, but need make after touch and when no choice any, but standart choice -Select-

Answer (score 0):

my final code. 
but not good what i want

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.gender.$pristine && myForm.gender.$invalid }">
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{getWord('Gender')}}<sup>*</sup></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <select ui-select2 ng-model="patient.gender" data-placeholder="Tên Cơ Sở" ng-change="changeGender(filterType)" style="width: 100%;" required name="gender">
                                        <option value="">-{{getWord('Select')}}-</option>
                                        <option ng-repeat="item in genders" value="{{item.name}}" >
                                            {{getWord(item.name)}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>

                                     <p style="color:red" ng-if="myForm.gender.$pristine || myForm.gender.$error.required">Please choice gender</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WskrN.png)